# JAXB search and delete element nodes

Tags: xml, dom, xpath, jaxb

I have converted my XSD files to JAVA objects using JAXB.

Next thing i did  was unmarshall the xml file to these objects.

Now my goal is to add, delete, search some nodes in the XML.

I am finding very hard to do this in JAXB.

for e.g I want to match any node whose attribute name="weight" .

How do i do this in JAXB objects?

In dom XML this searching/updating / deleting is very easy.

How can i do this in JAXB?

or e.g

I have an attribute name to match "Weight"    which is of type interfaceClass.

```
 <CAEXFile>
<InterfaceCLASSLIB>
<interfaceclass>
<attribute name="weight>
<../>
```

So in order to access interface class.

I will have to go through all objects hierarchy.

CAEXFile ---> get InterfaceClassLib() ---> getInterfaceClass()--> gettAttributes();

Note every get method returns a List of Array because there can be many interface class, attributes e.t.c .

This is a very expensive method then.

I didn't find any predefined function to reach to a particular node.

Any help would be appreciated. Should turn back DOM-XML for xml insert delete update.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said searching for nodes using JAXB is expensive. I would use [XPathFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPathFactory.html) available as part of standard Java to get the desired nodes.
Like below :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
   XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance();
   XPath xpath = xpf.newXPath();

   InputSource xml = new InputSource("<your_path_to_input.xml>");
   Object result = (Object) xpath.evaluate("//attribute[@name=\"weight\"]", xml, XPathConstants.NODESET);
   if ( result != null && result instanceof NodeList )
   {
      NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)result;
      if ( nodeList.getLength() > 0 )
      {
         for ( int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++ )
         {
            org.w3c.dom.Node node = nodeList.item( i );
            System.out.println(node.getNodeValue());
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The xpath is `//attribute[@name="weight"]`, it recursively searches xml for `attribute` nodes which have an attribute called `name` with value `weight`

Comment: Can I use jaxb and xpath factory together?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by "together" it depens on the problem you are trying to solve. JAXB is used for marshalling/unmarshalling XML whereas XPath factory is used only for XPath evaluations on a given xml when there is no need to serialize/deserialize.

Comment: I unmarshalled my xml file into a java object using jaxb, but now I need to perform the same operations that this post wants on my files. However, thinking back, I'm seeing the answer takes the result from the xml file whereby I would like to perform the operations on my java model itself, if that makes sense