# How can I search for a value in objects and print all instances where the value in true?

Tags: java

I have an xml file that I unmarshalled into a java object. Most cases that I have read about, when the user searches, they go through the nodes of the xml file and return the result. The question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849908/jaxb-search-and-delete-element-nodes) where I want to perform all the functions mentioned, but on the java object itself, not the xml. For this question I'm only focusing on the searching operation however and the only thing that the user can search for is the group name. If the group name that the user enters matches that of an object, then I'd like to print the object along with all of it's other variables. I'm not sure how to go about this. I'm currently stuck at the operation where I'll have to take the user input and loop through the objects and search against the group variable within the object.
All the files are available on [github](https://github.com/SodeshDindayal/Jaxb)

Main class

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JAXBException {

        File file = new File("items.xml");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Items.class);
        Unmarshaller un = context.createUnmarshaller();
        Items itemData = (Items) un.unmarshal(file);

        List<Item> items = itemData.getItem();

        for(Item e: items){
            System.out.println("\nDataType : "+e.getDataType());
            System.out.println("Name : "+e.getName());
            System.out.println("Data : "+e.getData());
            System.out.println("Group : "+e.getGroup());
            System.out.println("Sub Categories : " + e.getItems());
            System.out.println("--------------------------");
        }

        System.out.println("'\n\n------------- Options ---------------");
        System.out.println("\n1. Search Items by Group");
        String choice = scan.nextLine();

        if(choice == gr)


    }
}
```

Item Class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;

public class Item {
    private String dataType;
    private String name;
    private int data;
    private String group;
    private Items items;

    @XmlElement
    public String getDataType(){
        return dataType;
    }
    public void setDataType(String dataType){
        this.dataType = dataType;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public int getData(){
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(int data){
        this.data = data;
    }

    @XmlElement
    public String getGroup(){
        return group;
    }
    public void setGroup(String group){
        this.group = group;
    }

    public Items getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(Items items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return
                "\n\tDataType: " + dataType +
                "\n\tName: " + name +
                "\n\tData: " + data +
                "\n\tGroup: " + group +
                "\n\tItems: " + items + "\n";
    }
}
```

Items class

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "items")
public class Items {
    private List<Item> item;

    @XmlElement(name = "item")
    public List<Item> getItem(){
        return item;
    }

    public void setItem(List<Item> itemList){
        this.item = itemList;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "\n" + item ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understand your question correctly. Doesn't a simple filter satisfy your needs:

```
public static List<Item> findByGroup(List<Item> items, String group){
    return items.stream()
                .filter(i ->i.getGroup().equals(group))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Just for a quick test try

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, JAXBException {

    File file = new File("items.xml");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Items.class);
    Unmarshaller un = context.createUnmarshaller();
    Items itemData = (Items) un.unmarshal(file);

    List<Item> items = itemData.getItem();

    for(Item e: items){
        System.out.println("\nDataType : "+e.getDataType());
        System.out.println("Name : "+e.getName());
        System.out.println("Data : "+e.getData());
        System.out.println("Group : "+e.getGroup());
        System.out.println("Sub Categories : " + e.getItems());
        System.out.println("--------------------------");
    }

    System.out.println("'\n\n------------- Options ---------------");
    System.out.println("\n1. Search Items by Group");
    String choice = scan.nextLine();

     List<Item> filterdByGroup = items.stream()
                                      .filter(i ->i.getGroup().equals(choice))
                                      .collect(Collectors.toList());

     filterdByGroup.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Each object contains a group variable, where the group is stored. I basically just want to search for a group, and whichever object has the same group value must be displayed. I hope this clarifies.Can you break down what the filter does and how I can implement it?

Comment: Thanks, I understand now